# When only one job available take me to job listing not company page

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

If a company has more than one job available (say 5 jobs available) I agree that when clicking these **5 jobs available** should take you to the company page and to the anchor **jobs**.  However, if there is one single job available I think it would make more sense to direct right to the actual job.  It's one less click and doesn't really make sense to take them to the company page to the job anchor only to yet again show you that same job.